# Rename sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Can you help me to provide VBA code to rename all sheet based on call value available in A1 of each sheet but wanted to pick only 1st there word as sheet name

```
sub rename ()
    for each sht in thisworkbook.worksheets
        sht.name=sht.range("A1")
    next sht
```

This VBA is renaming all sheet but I want to capture only first three word from cell A1

For eg. `"A1" = "Fund GQ Jan Q1 2019"` so I need sheet name to be "Fund GQ Jan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little manipulation with the String will help:

See the use of `Left` and `Instr`

```
Sub rename()

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Name = Left(sht.Range("A1"), InStr(1, sht.Range("A1"), Split(sht.Range("A1"), " ")(3)) - 2)
    Next sht

End Sub
```